# Error: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.1' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I try to create MYSQL database. File create_db.py:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password  = "password123",
    )
my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE our_users")
my_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
for db in my_cursor:
     print(db)
```

I put the following command in windows CMD: `python create_db.py`. And there is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\create_db.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\path\virt\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 286, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\path\virt\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\path\virt\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\path\virt\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 273, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

```
    import mysql.connector

# Connect to the MySQL server
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="password123"
```

)

```
# Create a cursor object
my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

# Create the "our_users" database
my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE 
our_users")

# Show all databases
my_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

# Print the databases
for db in my_cursor:
    print(db)
```

You should run the following command in mysql command-line before running the python file :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
```